# Adding to an observable collection with alternate thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, observablecollection

I am adding to an observablecollection in an alternate thread and this collection is bound to a datagrid from the wpftoolkit.

The oncollectionchanged is invoking through the main gui thread when such an event occurs.

The problem I am seeing is that most of the time the application will throw:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
>     Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index
>     Source=mscorlib
>     ParamName=index
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
>          at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
>          at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index)
>          at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.InternalItemAt(Int32 index)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanupContainers(Int32 firstViewport, ItemsControl itemsControl)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
>          at Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\DataGrid\Microsoft\Windows\Controls\Primitives\DataGridRowsPresenter.cs:line 109
>          at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
>          at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
>          at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
>          at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
>          at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
>          at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>          at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.TranslateAndDispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
>          at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
>          at Apollo.App.Main() in F:\Workspaces\BVS\BVS\Apollo\Apollo\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0

Any thoughts on what this could be from? Here is the oncollectionchanged code:

```
protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (BlockReentrancy())
        {
            KeyValuePair<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, CollectionChangedEventData>[] handlers = _collectionChangedHandlers.ToArray();

            if (handlers.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, CollectionChangedEventData> kvp in handlers)
                {
                    if (kvp.Value.Dispatcher == null)
                    {
                        kvp.Value.Action(e);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        kvp.Value.Dispatcher.Invoke(kvp.Value.Action, DispatcherPriority.DataBind, e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why exactly are you handling (implementing) the CollectionChanged yourself?

Comment: Is more than one thread updating the collection?  The CollectionChanged handler in the ListCollectionView will look at the items in the list after it receives the notification and it expects that the state matches what the notification tells it.  If another thread modifies the collection after the Invoke starts, this will invalidate the original notification.

Comment: @HenkHolterman
This is being done because we wanted to have the collectionchanged event fire on the main thread versus the thread that was running in the background.

Comment: @DanBryant
No. There is only one thread updating the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top of that stacktrace suggest something going wrong in a normal `List<>` in a ListCollectionView.

You probably should look at the code that binds to SelectedItem et al.

Comment: Though not an absolute answer to the problem, it was a step in the right direction.
The problem was that the datagrid was trying to measure the columns because it saw a collection changed event. The wpf threads didn't have control of the collection changes coming in from the other thread. The next time a collection changed came in from another thread, the rendering process was probably interrupted and could not handle that unexpected event from the other thread.

Comment: The solution was to gather the data from its source (in this case sql) but use the main thread in side the background thread to add to the itemsource of the datagrid. From what I can understand, this allows the wpf threads to manage the gui changes successfully.

Comment: @Csharpfunbag The problem with this approach is that you loose some of the performance forcing all the addition to the ItemsSource to be sequencial.